# c expected ; before ) token

Tags: c++, c

```
void GravaFicheiros(CONFERENCIA *co)
{

    int i, ii, iii;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("grabameisso", "wt");

    fprintf (fp, "%s\n", co->nomeconf);

    int k = NSessoes(co);
    fprintf (fp, "%d\n", k);

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {

        fprintf (fp, "%s\n%d\n%d\n", co->sessoes[i].tema, co->sessoes[i].hora, co->sessoes[i].auditorio);

        int a = NArtigos(co, i);

        fprintf (fp, "%d\n", a);

        for (ii = 0; ii < a; ii++)
        {

            fprintf (fp, "%s\n", co->sessoes[i].artigos[ii].titulo);

            int aa = NAutores(co, i, ii);

            fprintf (fp, "%d\n", aa);

            for (iii = 0; iii < aa, iii++)
            {

                fprintf (fp, "%s\n%d\n", co->sessoes[i].artigos[ii].autores[iii].nome, co->sessoes[i].artigos[ii].autores[iii].idade);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return;
```

Comment: You did not actually ask a question. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). I'm going to close this question. Please put a little more effort into your "question" next time, such as actually asking one.

Answer (score 3):

Although you didn't ask a specific question I assume you want to know why there was an error in your code.

One of your for loops is missing a semi-colon.

> ```
> for (iii = 0; iii < aa, iii++) //this line gives the error
> ```

Should be:

```
 for (iii = 0; iii < aa; iii++) //the comma should be a semi-colon
```

When it says ; expected before token ). It means quite literally that there is a ; missing before a ).